# Use different comment template for replies-to-top-comment

Tags: 7, theming, comments

I tried to make StackExchange-like comment section with different template for the comment replies. I create two template for both top-level comment and its replies. This is the result of the two `comment.tpl.php` file rendered and then collated in GIMP.

[image: Desired result]

This is `comment.tpl.php` used for top comment contained in cyan box.

```
<div class="user-comment">
  <div<?php print $attributes; ?>>
    <div class="user-identification">
      <?
        print render($avatar) . "<br/>";
        print $commenter_name . "<br/>";
        print $creation_date;
      ?>
    </div>
    <?php
      hide($content['links']);
      print render($content['comment_body']);
      print render($content['links']);
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

While this is `comment.tpl.php` used for comment reply contained in yellow box.

```
<div class="user-comment">
  <div<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php
    print render($content['comment_body']);
    print " - " . $commenter_name;
    print render($content['links']);
   ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

If i use one of these template, it will effect ALL the comments as shown below.

[image: Reply to comment template]

I know I can change the style rudimentarily via theme css as suggested in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99633/theme-reply-comments-differently-from-node-comments-drupal-7), but going by this route means that I have to create one-size-fit-all template for both case that won't be pretty.

My question is: Is there any template file I missed or any other strategy that I can employ to make separate template that will target only the replies-to-top-comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve this problem by exploiting the `pid` (parent ID) value in the `$comment` variable. First, I check if the corresponding comment is a top-level comment. It is a top level comment if the `pid` value is `0`. The code inside `comment.tpl.php` so far is:

```
if ($comment->pid == 0) {
  // Top level comments code here
} else {
  // Replies to comments code here
}
```

The code above will split the template programatically already, but it will be better if I worked at two separate files for the two cases. To do this, I used [`drupal_get_path`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7.x) function to point every case inside `comment.tpl.php` to their corresponding template.

In my case, I create these two templates inside my theme folder:

- `/templates/comment/comment-top.tpl.php` for the top comment
- `/templates/comment/comment-reply.tpl.php` for the replies

The code inside `comment.tpl.php` then become:

```
if ($comment->pid == 0) {
  include drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .
    '/templates/comment/comment-top.tpl.php';
} else {
  include drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .
    '/templates/comment/comment-reply.tpl.php';
}
```

Of course change the `mytheme` in the code to your theme name.

To finish off, I pasted the template I posted above in the question to the corresponding template. It will render the template properly with all the variables you define inside the preprocesses function working.